# For-loop to get spotify tracks by album in R

Tags: r, api, for-loop, apply, libspotify

I am trying to write a for-loop to call multiple albums and retrieve the track id's and track names per album.

The original code works for **one** album:

```
spotifyKey <- "###########################"
spotifySecret <- "#######################"

library("httr")
library("jsonlite")

response = POST(
  'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  accept_json(),
  authenticate(spotifyKey, spotifySecret),
  body = list(grant_type = 'client_credentials'),
  encode = 'form',
  verbose()
)

token = content(response)$access_token

HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', token)


spotifyAlbum <- "2scB1uhcCI1TSf6b9TCZK3"
albumTracksURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/",
                    spotifyAlbum,"/tracks?limit=50",sep="")
getTracks <- GET(albumTracksURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
albumTracks <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getTracks)))
ids <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$id), 
                     nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$name), 
                       nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
result <- cbind(ids, names)
```

This is the output:

```
   matrix.unlist.albumTracks.items.id...nrow...albumTracks.total.. matrix.unlist.albumTracks.items.name...nrow...albumTracks.total..
1                                           0B1QILlvPWfc9vovFYuUuk                                             FutureSex / LoveSound
2                                           0O45fw2L5vsWpdsOdXwNAR                                                          SexyBack
3                                           5Gq7IN29DbgUO8Ris1TZKl                                                       Sexy Ladies
4                                           1vMuSYlp2Im8Gpj6JxRJfj                              Medley: Let Me Talk to You / My Love
5                                           5iyE2d4U3Vc5cqY9mPTlpy                        LoveStoned / I Think She Knows (Interlude)
6                                           3pD0f7hSJg2XdQ6udw5Tey                   What Goes Around.../...Comes Around (Interlude)
7                                           0LlObwsSjhvPFKPPpSWOeh                                                        Chop Me Up
8                                           4JQtyBEeLOAOnb7n5OQdDd                                                         Damn Girl
9                                           1MBM7CyZbwJpVbbZJnHHRg                                                       Summer Love
10                                          39q69v4D15oSshBmlJrkmW                      Set the Mood Prelude / Until the End of Time
11                                          1Ou4q1gX3QAvKhAFd3xsXT                                                     Losing My Way
12                                          24CBAWq81pQNTftNAxVLYk                                     (Another Song) All Over Again
```

How do I do this for **multiple** albums?

I tried creating a for-loop but that didn't work:

```
spotifyAlbum <- data.frame(c("62AITKgUMplmKKSTsTlDDo","2scB1uhcCI1TSf6b9TCZK3"))
colnames(spotifyAlbum)[1]<-"ALBUM"

for(i in 1:length(spotifyAlbum[,1])) {
albumTracksURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/",
                    spotifyAlbum[i,1],"/tracks?limit=50",sep="")
getTracks <- GET(albumTracksURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
albumTracks <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getTracks)))
ids <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$id), 
                     nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$name), 
                       nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
spotifyAlbum[,2] <- ids
spotifyAlbum[,3] <- names
}
```

Bonus point would be to include the album name too.

My goal is to have the final output look like this:

```
                       ID                                            NAME     ALBUM
1  0B1QILlvPWfc9vovFYuUuk                           FutureSex / LoveSound     FutureSex/LoveSounds
2  0O45fw2L5vsWpdsOdXwNAR                                        SexyBack    FutureSex/LoveSounds
3  5Gq7IN29DbgUO8Ris1TZKl                                     Sexy Ladies    FutureSex/LoveSounds
4  1vMuSYlp2Im8Gpj6JxRJfj            Medley: Let Me Talk to You / My Love    FutureSex/LoveSounds
5  5iyE2d4U3Vc5cqY9mPTlpy      LoveStoned / I Think She Knows (Interlude)    FutureSex/LoveSounds
6  3pD0f7hSJg2XdQ6udw5Tey What Goes Around.../...Comes Around (Interlude)    FutureSex/LoveSounds
7  0LlObwsSjhvPFKPPpSWOeh                                      Chop Me Up    FutureSex/LoveSounds
8  4JQtyBEeLOAOnb7n5OQdDd                                       Damn Girl    FutureSex/LoveSounds
9  1MBM7CyZbwJpVbbZJnHHRg                                     Summer Love    FutureSex/LoveSounds
10 39q69v4D15oSshBmlJrkmW    Set the Mood Prelude / Until the End of Time    FutureSex/LoveSounds
11 1Ou4q1gX3QAvKhAFd3xsXT                                   Losing My Way    FutureSex/LoveSounds
12 24CBAWq81pQNTftNAxVLYk                   (Another Song) All Over Again    FutureSex/LoveSounds
13 0KqpOdVQoDfeELTKYc97cO                        Piensas (Dile la Verdad)    Dale
14 2MRv991PzjY2ecCluXoRq9              Como Yo Le Doy - Spanglish Version    Dale
15 501PoxE6Qti2ekECimQeXK                                         El Taxi    Dale
16 2yUu771fYfHQa45VcVvkhS                   Yo Quiero (Si Tu Te Enamoras)    Dale
17 5KsChQslA4yRGInwDfGm9N                                        El Party    Dale
18 3yyXE55qVqIoYS9g3Q5LMM                                       Mami Mami    Dale
19 3NW0zAs5TXnfoyWuTPdyjP                            Baddest Girl in Town    Dale
20 59db0pQBOuB1FgjLo7RlvH                                 Chi Chi Bon Bon    Dale
21 2iRSdAGD6fbY2SdJ2wnTal                                  Haciendo Ruido    Dale
22 4BmLLPmR24ExGQyqhJH8i2                                     Hoy Se Bebe    Dale
23 62NKyNgp1yBp2KYRHIm2ou                                    No Puedo Más    Dale
24 0fafrbr2rolcqdV1aOkI6n                                      Que Lo Que    Dale
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may get you what you're after.

```
spotifyKey <- "###########################"
spotifySecret <- "#######################"

library("httr")
library("jsonlite")

response = POST(
  'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  accept_json(),
  authenticate(spotifyKey, spotifySecret),
  body = list(grant_type = 'client_credentials'),
  encode = 'form',
  verbose()
)

token = content(response)$access_token

HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', token)

spotifyAlbums <- c("62AITKgUMplmKKSTsTlDDo","2scB1uhcCI1TSf6b9TCZK3")

get.tracks <- function(spotifyAlbum){
  albumTracksURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/", spotifyAlbum, "/tracks?limit=50", sep="")
  getTracks <- GET(albumTracksURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
  albumTracks <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getTracks)))

  ids <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$id), 
                           nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  names <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$name), 
                             nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  artists <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$artists), nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  result <- cbind(ids, names)

  colnames(result) <- c("ID", "NAME")

  return(result)
}

df <- lapply(spotifyAlbums, get.tracks)

df <- do.call(rbind, df)
```

Modified function

```
 get.tracks <- function(spotifyAlbum){
    albumTracksURL <- paste("https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/", spotifyAlbum, "/tracks?limit=50", sep="")
    getTracks <- GET(albumTracksURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
    albumTracks <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getTracks)))

    ids <- unlist(albumTracks$items$id)

    names <- unlist(albumTracks$items$name)

    artists <- paste(unlist(albumTracks$items$artists), collapse = "; ")

    result <- data.frame(ID = ids, NAME = names, ARTIST = artists, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    return(result)
}
```

Comment: do you get an error when you try to include the artist in the function()?   `artists <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(albumTracks$items$artists), nrow=albumTracks$total, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: If you add in artist, you would need to make sure and make these two changes `result <- cbind(ids, names, artists)` and `colnames(result) <- c("ID", "NAME","ARTIST")`

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but then an error comes up saying: `Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match`

Comment: I'm doing it with 10 different albums by the way

Comment: [1] "4fzcRcvBa01ytHh08HnI3D" "4skCiJhVVSKrDOBtoFbsxU" "0QqrTxRtjqQmH5XyqwORlU" "5m9rXTBF7mHFGQlFsiEHrY" "3rnhvfgbXmDAcESeGp69Tx"
 [6] "6oPAq3tPMGIvlpjoscQP4g" "4wFbU3Szo2ztrN7zGHmWVe" "0gmjYisnPhgbCL1HNfSc7O" "5T4Y6MQTsEENBa5FYK2ux7" "4pfzhxwwQy4B8lySxjwKdt"

Comment: Can you check if you get the same error? I can make this another post if you would prefer that

Comment: I'm looking into it and it becomes tough actually because you can have a different number of artists for each song and there are columns within each list entry that need to be subsetted. I need to do more research on this because I think it is a more advanced question for what you answered. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I actually don't have a Spotify account to test any of this with, but I added a modified version of the function to my answer that may work for this problem.